# activerecord query for an array of arrays

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

I have the following models:

```
Notification
  belongs_to :receiver, class_name: 'User'
  # has a sent_email boolean column default set to false

User
  has_many :received_notifications, class_name: 'Notification', foreign_key: 'receiver_id', inverse_of: :receiver
  has_one :alert

Alert
  belongs_to :user
  # has a frequency integer column
```

I want to grab all the notifications where the sent_email is false for all users who set their alert frequency to 1, and I want the return result to be something like this:

```
    [
       {user object => [<all of the notifications for user 1>]},
       {user object => [<all of the notifications for user 2>]}    
    ]
```

I want it to be 1 or 2 queries at most.

What would the activerecord query look like?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `includes`.

```
u = User.includes(:received_notifications, :alert)
        .where("alerts.frequency_discussion_alerts = ? AND notifications.sent_email = ?", 1, false)
        .references(:notifications,:alerts)
```

Now in batch, you can fetch users and do your job.

```
 u.find_each { |u| u.received_notifications }
```

Comment: Thanks @R_O_R but it returns all the records in a single array. 

Is there a way to get all the notifications for each specific reciever_id in its own array inside of an array?

Comment: @PavanKatepalli Yes.. call map and build you hash.

Comment: @PavanKatepalli what is your db client ? Postgresql?

Comment: The issue with .map could be that I have 20,000 notifications to map over. Do you see that being an issue?

Comment: @PavanKatepalli try, `.select("users.id*, notifications.*").group("users.id")` ... `map` is not a good idea for large data.

Comment: thanks R_O_R. I couldn't just group by the users.id, I had to group by users.id, notifications.id or I got an error. 

Unfortunately, the result was just an array. Any other ideas?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/79531/discussion-between-r-o-r-and-pavan-katepalli).

Comment: @PavanKatepalli Pls join the chat.